# How to choose correct value range of green colour from histogram charts

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I tried to segment just leaves from plant image. I spend 2 weeks googling about how to extract correct range value for green colour from the histogram of the hue, saturation and value colour space. I used the following codes:

```
hsv=rgb2hsv(INSUM);
H1=hsv(:,:,1);
figure, imshow(H1);
H2=hsv(:,:,2);
figure, imshow(H2);
H3=hsv(:,:,3);
figure, imshow(H3)
H1(H1(:)==0)=[];
H2(H2(:)==0)=[];
H3(H3(:)==0)=[];
figure,imhist(H1);
figure,imhist(H2);
figure,imhist(H3);

limitUpperH = 0.3; limitLowerH = 0.19;  
limitUpperS = 1; limitLowerS = 0.95;  
limitUpperV = 0.6; limitLowerV = 0.02;

LOGICH = (hsv(:,:,1)<limitUpperH) & (hsv(:,:,1)>limitLowerH);
LOGICS = (hsv(:,:,2)<limitUpperS) & (hsv(:,:,2)>limitLowerS);
LOGICV = (hsv(:,:,3)<limitUpperV) & (hsv(:,:,3)>limitLowerV);
LOGIC = LOGICH & LOGICS & LOGICV;
figure() imshow(LOGIC);
```

I choose the limitUpper and limitLower for the H, S and V works for just one image by trial and error and they give good result for just one image, but when I apply these values on other images it doesn’t work.

I read many things and saw many examples about the HSV and image histogram but none say how to extract green range of h, s and v from histogram chart. Can any one help me?

Comment: Try just using the `Hue` value to segment, then all different saturations (`S`) of green will be found, and all different brightnesses (`V`) of green will also still be found.

Comment: The notion of "green" is quite subjective: if you check the HSV (or RGB) values of pixels that you perceive as "green" in different pictures you'll notice there is quite a variance to these values. What you think is "green" can be significantly affected by shading, neighboring colors and other effects.

Comment: You mind find [this](http://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/vandeweijer/color_names.html) research project relevant to your problem.

Comment: Thank you Mark for your answer the results were improved when I ignore the s and v channels, however it is not work for all images.

Comment: Thank Shai for your answer, it looks more suitable for my case, as you said there a different gradient of green for each image. I applied the example on my image and I obtained the result as attached, do you think this is right result and why the yellow colour is appears? Is there is so something I must do as a setting for the example to detect the green colour?

Comment: How can I upload an image?